# Silverlight ProjectionPlane Oddity

Tags: silverlight

I have this panel in my app which is 10400 pixels wide.

I have my CenterOfRotationX and CenterOfRotationZ = 0.5.

I have the GlobalOffsets configured so that the rotation of the panel is visible on the screen.

This video shows the RotationY being set from -180 to 180.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDrETOueb-w

Its really weird at RotationY = 90 (about 13 seconds on the video), it seems to get stretched to hell when I would expect it to disappear from view.

Also from about 8 - 9 seconds on the video shows the panel starting at RotationY = 0 to RotationY = 20, where it starts to stretch. Over this small rotation it appears to nearly rotate 180 degrees.

Maybe I have some settings wrong but this seems really strange. - The only value changing in this video is the RotationY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the GlobalOffsetX variable on the ProjectionPlane.

This was set to something astronomical so I could see the full rotation on the screen but this had an effect on the rotation.

Setting this to 0 and then moving the Plane to the left using the Canvas.LeftProperty fixed this.